# Overshoot on dc/dc converter

Tags: voltage, buck, ldo, linear-regulator, overshoot

Any idea on what would the level of overshoot that this [LDO](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/mic5301.pdf) can provide?

Would that data/information on overshoot would be provided in the datasheet? If not, how should I understand that?

I am using this LDO for 5 V to 1.8 V output with a load current of 10 mA.
I am getting an overshoot up to 2 V and then returns to 1.8 V.

Is a 200 mV overshoot ok for this IC? Would it matter if I connect load to this output or not?

Comment: What’s your output capacitance?

Comment: @winny. I have 1uF of input and output capacitance. Is 0.2V of overshoot acceptable? Asking since the overshoot is only 200mV

Answer (score 0):

There is an example diagram of transient behaviour in the datasheet.

The datasheet also says the regulator is stable under no load conditions.

But the behaviour depends on how much capacitance you have, is it the correct type of capacitance for the regulator to be stable, and what is your transient load current, all of which you don't say so exact answer cannot be given if what you see is normal.

Comment: Thank you. I have 1uF of input and output capacitance.

Comment: Is 0.2V of overshoot acceptable? Asking since the overshoot is only 200mV

Comment: @Freshman If your circuit can handle it then yes, otherwise no. We can't know what is acceptable by your circuit. You never said what 1uF caps you use, they may be of wrong type and they ruin your regulator response. We also don't know how you trigger the overshoot to happen. How much is the load step, more or less than in the datasheet example?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Could you tell me what capacitors would be the wrong type as you mention? I am using 0402 X5R capacitors.

Comment: The datasheet says what are recommended and what not. You at least have the recommended cap dielectric. Still, you never mention what is the test case where you observe the overshoot.